# Passportjs always fails the authentication

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js

I am trying to use `passportjs` with the following code.

So when the user goes to `http://localhost:3000`, he should automatically be redirected to `/hello` but as it does, it redirects to `/hello?failure`.

I have tried to debug, look around but haven't found the issue and the solution.

```
const express = require('express');
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const session = require('express-session');


let app = express();

app.use(session({
    secret: 'mysecret',
    cookie: {
        secure: false
    },
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}
));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions

passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy(function (username, password, done) {

    console.log(username + ' username ');
    console.log(password + ' password ');

    return done(null, { name: 'suhail' });
}));


passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    console.log(user, ' serialize ');
    done(null, user.name);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    console.log(id, ' deserialize ');
    done(null, { name: 'suhail' });
});

app.get('/', passport.authenticate('local-login', { successRedirect: '/hello', failureRedirect: '/hello?failure' }));


app.get('/hello', (req, resp, next) => resp.send('hello').end());

app.listen(3000);
```

What is it that I am missing? It should go to `http://localhost:3000/hello` as the middleware always resolves.

Note:
- None of the middleware defined is called. It just redirects to `/hello?failure` when a GET request to `/` is made.

Comment: can you be a bit more specific, which function is being called when? aka, can you post the resulting logs?

Comment: @JohannesMerz Have added a note. None of the middleware defined is called. It just redirects to `/hello?failure`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not providing username and password in your get request. Therefore the Strategycallback is never called.

Try adding this middleware in front of your routing to see what i mean:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    // fake body content for authentication
    req.body = {username: 'devil', password: '666'}
    next()
})
app.get('/', passport.authenticate('local-login', { successRedirect: '/hello', failureRedirect: '/hello?failure' }));
```